# NestJS class validator doesn't validate the data

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

class validator doesn't work in nestjs application. Please help! Thanks!

DTO:

```
import {
  IsNotEmpty,
  IsDate,
  IsDateString,
  IsMobilePhone,
  IsISO8601,
  IsBoolean,
  IsEmail,
  MaxLength,
} from 'class-validator';

    export class UserEducationDto {
      @IsBoolean()
      degree: boolean;
    
      subjectMajor: string;
      subjectMinor: string;
      yearOfPassing: string;
      obtainedMarks: string;
      marksType: string;
      grade: string;
      institute: string;
      instituteAddress: string;
      instituteContactNo: string;
      instituteEmail: string;
      university: string;
      universityRegNo: string;
      universityRollNo: string;
      id?: string;
      education?: object;
      userId?: string;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@Post('/education')
  @ApiHeader({
    name: 'userId',
    description: 'userId',
  })
  async addEducationDetails(
    @Body() profileData: object,
    @GetUser() userId: any,
  ) {
      let profileDetails = new UserEducationDto();
    }
```

main.ts:
I have added `app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());`

It still doesn't validate and throw any message related to error.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing the object yourself, so there will be no validation unless you invoke it manually. The type has to be used on the input parameter of the action so the framework will construct and validate it.

So something like:

```
async addEducationDetails(
    @Body() profileData: UserEducationDto, // <- this
    @GetUser() userId: any,
)
```

Comment: I am passing a dynamic object, how to proceed in this scenario?

Comment: @ShreyasMurali What do you mean by "dynamic object"?

Comment: I meant dynamic json object.

Comment: That is usually what you send to an API like that, Nest should handle that just fine. That is the whole point of having a validation pipe, to convert some JSON into a validated class instance.

Comment: The dynamic object is the "profileData" which comes in the html body. UserEducationDto is the type that refers to the class where the validation rules are stored.